# jdbc Connection time out error while connecting spark application to a remote sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc

I have a pyspark application which fetches data from a a remote sql server , It

was working fine until recently and I have upgraded my sql server 2016 CTP3 to sql

server 2016 RC3 developer version ,Now I am not able to connect to the database any more ,with the same configuration I was able to connect . I am not sure whats going on and tried all possible ways to figure it out .

error message :

```
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host myserver.cloudapp.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."
```

I know why it occurs and what are possible reasons and I have ensured in every possible way to counter that

1. stopped the firewall in [myserver]
2. ensured my sqlserver service is running
3. in its configurations manager I have enabled the tcp ip connection and its listening to all IPs in 1433 port .
4. [image]
   [image]

my spark application resides in a azure HDInsight spark cluster and my sql

server database is in a windows 2012 server( not sure if this makes any

difference) ,although I was able to connect from the same cluster to the previous windows server with the same configuratio

Now `netstat -a` in my server shows there are multiple established connections in where local address is my machines IP and port is 1433.there are few time out requests as well but they are not in 1433 port ,which I assume means they are not related with my sql server connection .

is there a way I can find out whats wrong in here , I think I have covered all possible causes where it might happen but I still get this error

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of effort I found that  my problem was the cloud firewall ,so if you are using Azure or AWS ,make sure you are opening the port 1433 in your cloud firewall as well . Hope this helps somebody .